# Integrate PDFTRON Web Viewer SDK for WPF app

Tags: pdftron

If there is any way of integrating PDFTRON Web Viewer SDK for WPF app(.Net Framework).?

I do not want to use the PDFTRON .Net SDK

Kindy help.